# How do I trigger an Azure function on completion of X number of other Azure functions?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure function that is triggered on the addition of a file to blob storage and a service that takes one large file, splits it into X number of smaller files, and uploads those smaller files to Azure Blob Storage which then kicks X Azure Functions. When all of these functions complete, I would like to kick off another Azure function to do more work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the Durable Functions for that : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp#fan-in-out

Comment: To expand on this answer, this is a combination of the fan-out/fan-in pattern linked to, as well as the function chaining pattern.